# Fastest way to compute the difference between two uint8_t variables?

Tags: c++

I have to compute the difference between two `uint8_t` variables in an *extremely* efficiency-sensitive area of code. It is imperative that I find the fastest way possible to execute this computation. This is for a program written in C++ running on Ubuntu.

I currently use the following macro:

```cpp
#define UINT8_T_DIFF(a, b) (static_cast<uint8_t>(((a > b) ? (a - b) : (b - a))))
```

This macro yields answer I need, but I'm wondering if there's something I can do to make this computation any faster?

Please note that I have the `static_cast` in the macro because without it I get a compiler message that:

```
conversion to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
```

Comment: Let's clarify: do you definitely need the absolute value of the difference? What do you do with it?

Comment: Thanks ClickRick, to clarify: The macro as written gives the exact answer I need. I am hoping for a faster way to compute this answer.

Comment: Did you try `std::abs(a - b)`?

Comment: In any case I would make this macro into a function. It will be inlined anyway, but right now you are evaluating the operands multiple times.

Comment: And in a macro you should remember to put parens around all the variables, to prevent problems due to operator precedence. `(static_cast<uint8_t>((a) > (b) ? (a) - (b) : (b) - (a)))`

Comment: I'd call this premature optimisation.  CPU's are extremely fast at addition and subtraction.  Look at other areas to optimise and run a profiler.   Let the compiler work out how to best optimise it.   If you were looking at really huge numbers the answer would be different.

Comment: @Matt The bottleneck in the *presented* code is actually the branch, not subtraction, unless the compiler is smart enough to recognize the pattern. But even with that in mind I would call the whole thing premature optimization...

Comment: You should show more of the code you are optimizing. Execution speed depends on a context a lot, because of deep CPU pipelines. The times when it was possible to hand optimize short computations like this are long gone.

Comment: Another option: `std::max(a, b) - std::min(a, b)`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - the bottleneck in the presented code is the branch as long as the code is not optimised by the compiler.   You'll be hard-pressed to find a modern compiler (say, more recent than the mid 90s) that cannot eliminate the branch as a trivial transformation to suitable machine instructions even when optimisation is disabled.    Which means, even though he focused on the addition and subtraction,  Matt is right in describing this question as premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford a time-space tradeoff, it only takes 64K to hold a lookup table of the results.

```
const uint8_t abs_diff[256][256] = 
    {{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 255},
     {1, 0, 1, 2, ..., 254},
     {2, 1, 0, 1, ..., 253},
     ...
     {255, 254, 253, ..., 0}};

#define UINT8_T_DIFF(a, b) (abs_diff[a][b])
```

Maybe cache misses will make this not worth it. But if you're using the macro in an inner loop, it may be able to keep most of it in cache during that time period.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Can you please explain what you mean by "cache misses"?

Comment: You're doing this level of optimization and you don't know how memory caching works? https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/04wi/section/378Caching.pdf and  https://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/ACCU2011_CPUCaches.pdf#targetText=On%20Core%20i7%2C%20cache%20lines,64-bit%20values%2C%20etc.&targetText=Main%20memory%20read%2Fwritten%20in%20terms%20of%20cache%20lines.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this level of optimization and I don't know how memory caching works.

Comment: OK, read those powerpoints and you'll learn all about it.

Comment: I selected this answer because it yielded the fastest results in my testing.

Comment: Wow, I was reluctant to post it because I was worried that it wouldn't be good enough.

Answer (score 9):

As a general rule, compilers usually generate the most optimized assembly when you write your source in a way that most obviously communicates your intent. This is what you want to do:

```
uint8_t diff(uint8_t a, uint8_t b) {
    return abs(a - b);
}
```

You can see how some compilers compile this on [Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3_2sbL). In particular GCC has an interesting sequence that doesn't use any branches or CMOV instructions:

```
movzx   eax, dil
movzx   esi, sil
sub     eax, esi
cdq
xor     eax, edx
sub     eax, edx
ret
```

This uses the trick where we can take the absolute value of a register by sign-extending it, XORing the upper half with the lower half, and subtracting the upper half from the lower half. Meanwhile, Clang uses a CMOV instruction. I have no idea which one performs better in practice. You may need to benchmark them on the specific architecture you're targeting.

As this is a common operation, I doubt that there's any assembly you can write by hand that would be faster than both of these approaches.

Comment: Great answer.  Bravo! +1 for recognising how good compilers are at optimising code these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the branch as follows:

```
(uint8_t)((a > b) * (a - b) + (a <= b) * (b - a))
```

Multiplying each by the result of the corresponding comparison results in the condition you don't want getting reduced to 0.

Comment: Does this actually improve the generated code's performance?

Comment: @uneven_mark I was wondering that, too -- it might because no branches pipelines better.

Comment: I doubt it would end up being any faster in practise.

Comment: Comparison (resulting in a bool) may be easily compiled as branch - this really depends on a platform.

Comment: GCC seems to remove the branch in OP's code anyway, generating identical assembly (x64 and arm), but clang seems to actually generate different code at least: https://godbolt.org/z/9-uaDx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am leaving work soon but will give this a try on Monday.